# Gaining access to Amazon FBA database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sdk, amazon-mws

I have more of a conceptual question here, but I think there should be a clear answer. I have a client who sells products using the "Fullfillment by Amazon" service. I am creating a Wordpress site for him to sell his products - and I am wondering what the easiest way to gain direct access to the Fulfillment by Amazon MySQL database would be. I know PHP/MySQL well...but I have never set up a retail site like this using Amazon services.

I did some googling - and found an old project called `tarzan-aws`, which has just turned into the `AWS` SDK now. But it looks like if I wanted to use that (if that is what I want to use), I would need to have a database hosted by Amazon AWS...and I already have a hosting service that I like (inmotionhosting.com). Is there a PHP API I could use to link the site to Fullfillment by Amazon? Maybe a Wordpress plugin? I logged into my clients FBA account and it doesn't seem like there is anyway to get the info I would need to set up a working automated PHP/Wordpress backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Amazon MWS API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/). They provide a guide, [Amazon MWS For FBA Sellers](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/fba/MWSForFBASellers._V344220563_.pdf), along with client libraries in PHP, C# and Java. You will not interact with a "database" as you have described; you will interact with a web service.